# Why do these images have left margin?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm not sure why the images on section 2 and section 4 have left margin when the media query kicks in at 960px wide. Section 3 doesn't have this problem and displays properly. If I remove the css for 1170px wide and keep just the css used in the media query then the images display perfectly. What am I doing wrong? I've attached a screenshot of the problem

[image]

```css
.container2 {
 margin: 75px auto;
 max-width: 1170px;
 display: flex;
}

.container2 .section2-text {
 flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 30px);
 margin: 0 30px 0 0;
}

.container2 .section2-img {
 flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 30px);
 margin: 0 0 0 30px;
}
.section2-img img {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 display: block;
}

/* section 3 */
.container3 {
 margin: 75px auto;
 max-width: 1170px;
 display: flex;
}

.container3 .section3-text {
 flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 30px);
 margin: 0 30px 0 0;
}

.container3 .section3-img {
 flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 30px);
 margin: 0 30px 0 0;
}
.section3-img img {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 display: block;
}

.container3 .section3-text {
 margin: 0 0 0 30px;
 order: 1;
}

/*section 4 */

.container4 {
 margin: 75px auto;
 max-width: 1170px;
 display: flex;
}

.container4 .section4-text {
 flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 30px);
 margin: 0 30px 0 0;
}

.container4 .section4-img {
 flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 30px);
 margin: 0 0 0 30px;
}
.section4-img img {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 display: block;
}

@media (max-width: 960px) {
 .container2 {
  margin: 40px auto;
 }
 /* section 2 */
 .container2 {
  margin: 0 20px;
  padding: 50px 0;
  max-width: 960px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
 }

 .container2 .section2-text {
  margin: 30px 0 0 0;
 }

 .container2 .section2-img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
 }

 .container2 .section2-text {
  order: 2;
 }

 .cotainer2 .section2-img {
  order: 1;
 }

 /* Section 3 */

 .container3 {
  margin: 0 20px;
  padding: 50px 0;
  max-width: 960px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
 }

 .container3 .section3-text {
  margin: 30px 0 0 0;
 }

 .container3 .section3-img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
 }

 .container3 .section3-text {
  order: 2;
 }

 .cotainer3 .section3-img {
  order: 1;
 }

 /* Section 4 */

 .container4 {
  margin: 0 20px;
  padding: 50px 0;
  max-width: 960px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
 }

 .container4 .section4-text {
  margin: 30px 0 0 0;
 }

 .container4 .section4-img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
 }

 .container4 .section4-text {
  order: 2;
 }

 .cotainer4 .section4-img {
  order: 1;
 }
}
```

```html
 <section class="container2">
        <div class="section2-text">
            <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame. </h2>
            <p>Morbi sit amet varius nunc, blandit vulputate mi. Nulla a lobortis magna. Ut bibendum, augue quis lacinia tempus, justo ligula tincidunt ligula, eu bibendum ante libero imperdiet magna. Mauris vel consectetur arcu. Pellentesque risus tortor, lacinia nec dictum a, sagittis quis turpis. Aliquam dolor ante, rhoncus nec congue at, dictum vitae eros. Integer nec viverra leo. Curabitur blandit pretium rhoncus. In ut egestas elit </p>
            <button>READ MORE</button>
        </div>
        <div class="section2-img">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/528x396" alt="">
        </div>
        </section>
        
        <section class="container3">
            <div class="section3-text">
                <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame.</h2>
                <p>Morbi sit amet varius nunc, blandit vulputate mi. Nulla a lobortis magna. Ut bibendum, augue quis lacinia tempus, justo ligula tincidunt ligula, eu bibendum ante libero imperdiet magna. Mauris vel consectetur arcu. Pellentesque risus tortor, lacinia nec dictum a, sagittis quis turpis. Aliquam dolor ante, rhoncus nec congue at, dictum vitae eros. Integer nec viverra leo. Curabitur blandit pretium rhoncus. In ut egestas elit</p>
                <button>READ MORE</button>
            </div>
            <div class="section3-img">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/528x396" alt="">
            </div>
        </section>

        <section class="container4">
            <div class="section4-text">
                <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame.</h2>
                <p>Morbi sit amet varius nunc, blandit vulputate mi. Nulla a lobortis magna. Ut bibendum, augue quis lacinia tempus, justo ligula tincidunt ligula, eu bibendum ante libero imperdiet magna. Mauris vel consectetur arcu. Pellentesque risus tortor, lacinia nec dictum a, sagittis quis turpis. Aliquam dolor ante, rhoncus nec congue at, dictum vitae eros. Integer nec viverra leo. Curabitur blandit pretium rhoncus. In ut egestas elit</p>
                <button>READ MORE</button>
            </div>
            <div class="section4-img">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/528x396">
            </div>
            </section>
```

Comment: Use the inspector built into your browser to see why. Right click the element and choose inspect, then start looking around. Hint: `.container2 .section2-img {
    flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 30px);
    margin: 0 0 0 30px;
}`

Comment: Because you have the margin set prior to the `media` query - those CSS rules will still apply unless you specifically overwrite them.

Comment: I hit you up in our chat from one of your last questions. On a side note, you can really simplify your HTML/CSS. You are doing a ton of unnecessary repetition of code.

Comment: I've set new margins though after the media query, and shouldn't section 3 have the same problem as section 2 and 4 if that was the case?

Comment: No where in your media query are you setting margin on the `.section*-img` elements.

Answer (score 1):

This is inherited from flex.
add `margins: 0` in `@media (max-width: 960px)` as in the follwoing:

```
.container2 .section2-img {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        margin: 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

At the first you must use

*{margin: 0;padding: 0;box-sizing: border-box;}

in your top of CSS file.

Comment: This will not work and is also a very heavy handed approach to this issue.